# Mouse-over Navigation Dropdown Menu Using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I would like to ask, if there is any way to develop a mouse-over dropdown menue using CSS and HTML, because I have seen before some websites like google for example developed such menus and it seems that once you pass through it a hidden  tag gonna be visible to you.

Please if any one have an idea, provide a source code of that idea

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I can explain it better than this: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

That's what's known as "Son of Suckerfish Dropdowns". It should get you going on the right direction. Do be aware that CSS-only dropdowns won't work in IE 6 and older.

Comment: I didn't recall when IE started supporting :hover on non-anchor elements, that's why I said "I think." Looks like its IE6 and below. Updated answer to reflect.

Comment: +1 for referencing a good tutorial on how you should be making menu structures.

Answer (score 5):

This is referred to a CSS hover menu. They're a great alternative to using JavaScript.

Sample implementation:

```
.trigger ul.menu
{
    display: none;
}
.trigger:hover ul.menu
{
    display: block;
}
```

Sample Tutorial: http://www.shingokko.com/blog-entry/pure-css-hover-menu.html

Contrary to other answers, this method **is** cross-browser compatible. If implemented correctly, it will work just fine in IE6+ [(Source)](http://www.grc.com/menu2/invitro.htm).

Comment: Nice table/conditional comment hackery, it's ugly but I'll at least admit it works. Heres a tip: drop IE6 support and you don't need any of that.

Comment: I agree this, more elegant and easier